# How do I make more fields drop down

Tags: picklist

Hi I am trying to create the following fields

**Industry/Type of work for past 10 years**-Section

**Current position/industry**
**Length of time in position/industry**

**Prior position/Industry**
**Length of time in position/industry**

However I want to display more fields if the person has worked in more Industries/or have more than 1 prior experience with a plus sign to drop down more Prior position/Industry fields and length of time fields.
How do I create it
[image]

Comment: Showing us an example of what you want (and what you've researched and tried so far) would be helpful. This site _thrives_ on details. From the sound of it, there's an issue here with your data model. You don't need additional fields, but rather an additional object. E.g. You have a `Resume__c` object to hold basic details, and an `Experience__c` object to hold picklists for Industry and Length.

Comment: @DerekF screen shot has been added

Comment: Once you have restructured your data model as Derek suggests, you can use either the standard Related List functionality for users to create records, or build a screen flow for a custom experience.

Comment: Putting this in other words. Instead of having a single `Survey__c` object with `Question_1__c`, `Answer_1__c`, `Question_2__c`, `Answer_2__c`, etc... The better design is to separate those into additional objects (`Survey__c`, and `QuestionAndAnswer__c` with a relationship to `Survey__c`) so that you don't need to make a change _every time you find someone who has 1 more question/answer than you previously planned for_.